# Spring Security:Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a X-Auth-Token from a user. But, when I try to retrieve the user from the generated token then it gives me an exception

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.security.util.AppConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.security.util.AppConfig threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7e618679; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.security.util.TokenHandler.fromJSON(TokenHandler.java:81)
    at com.security.util.TokenHandler.parseUserFromToken(TokenHandler.java:55)
    at com.security.util.TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationService.java:43)
    at com.security.util.StatelessAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(StatelessAuthenticationFilter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7e618679; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2648)
    at com.security.util.TokenHandler.fromJSON(TokenHandler.java:79)
    ... 42 more
```

For token generation I am using:

```
public String createTokenForUser(UserDetails user) {
        byte[] userBytes = toJSON(user);
        byte[] hash = createHmac(userBytes);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(170);
        sb.append(toBase64(userBytes));
        sb.append(SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(toBase64(hash));
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And in order to retrieve a user from token I am using:

```
public UserDetails parseUserFromToken(String token) {
        final String[] parts = token.split(SEPARATOR_SPLITTER);
        if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].length() > 0 && parts[1].length() > 0) {
            try {
                final byte[] userBytes = fromBase64(parts[0]);
                final byte[] hash = fromBase64(parts[1]);

                boolean validHash = Arrays.equals(createHmac(userBytes), hash);
                if (validHash) {
                   //NEXT LINE I GET AN EXCEPTION
                    final UserDetails user = fromJSON(userBytes);
                        return user;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                //log tempering attempt here
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

These are the other utility methods that was consumed in the above code:

```
  private UserDetails fromJSON(final byte[] userBytes) {
            try {
                return new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(userBytes), UserDetails.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }

        private byte[] toJSON(UserDetails user) {
            try {
                return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(user);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }

        private String toBase64(byte[] content) {
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(content);
        }

        private byte[] fromBase64(String content) {
            return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(content);
        }

        // synchronized to guard internal hmac object
        private synchronized byte[] createHmac(byte[] content) {
            return hmac.doFinal(content);
        }


EDIT # 1:

public class CustomUserDetails extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User{

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }


    public CustomUserDetails(User user, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(User user, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And modified my toJSON and fromJSON Method

```
private UserDetails fromJSON(final byte[] userBytes) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(userBytes), CustomUserDetails.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] toJSON(UserDetails user) {
        try {

            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes( new CustomUserDetails(
                                user.getUsername(),
                                     user.getPassword(),  user.getAuthorities()));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

Now the exception is a changed to : 
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.security.CustomUserDetails]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can write your own deserializer. Put JsonDeserialize annotation on related field.

```
    public class LoginUser implements UserDetails {

    ....getters and setters...

        @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomAuthorityDeserializer.class)
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return this.mAuthorities;
        }
}
```

Create deserializer for that field.

```
public class CustomAuthorityDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jp);
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new LinkedList<>();

        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = jsonNode.elements();
        while (elements.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode next = elements.next();
            JsonNode authority = next.get("authority");
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.asText()));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserDetails` is an interface, this is the reason of your error the `ObjectMapper` `read()` method is trying to instantiate it and failing. Provide a custom implementation of `UserDetails` as an argument of `ObjectMapper.read()` method and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I have added an implementation for UserDetails and also modified my two methods. But, now getting another exception

Comment: You should implement `UserDetails` not `User` and provide it to `ObjectMapper.readValue()`. Can you update the question with the new error?

Comment: I have implemented user details. I have already updated the exception in the last line. No suitable constructor found for type.